# How to Boolean mask the same object multiple instances?

Tags: modifiers, instances, masking

I have a Boolean mask with 4 numbers, each 2nd frame reveals a number. I have parented and kept the transformation to an empty object. I then duplicate the first batch of numbers which are masked with the boolean, but the boolean mask isnt working for the other instances, only for the first one which you can see the cubes. During the boolean mask, I do select Location, so Im considering this could be the issue, because the cubes reveal the numbers where the location of the mask has the frame set to be. So how can I make this work, having as many as I want to reveal the numbers using the boolean mask operation?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you animate objects, they animate relative to their position in the world, and if you copy and move them, when animated they will try to return to their position in the world. But if after animating you parent these objects to another, you can move the animated objects by moving the parent object and the new parent object behaves as an offset for the animated objects.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Leonardo, it worked!

Kind regards.